# CSS bouncing line loader animation

Tags: html, css, animation

Im trying to create a simple loader animation that draws a line back and forth but currently is moving only in one direction. As soon as it reaches the middle of the animation it does not animate in the oposite direction.

This is my css

```
@keyframes loader-animation {
     0% {
          width: 0%;
     }

     49% {
         width: 100%;
     }

     50% {
         left: 100%;
     }

     100% {
         left: 0%;
         width: 100%
     }
 }

 .loader {
     height: 5px;
     width: 100%;
 }

 .loader .bar {
     position: relative;
     height: 5px;
     background-color: dodgerblue;
     animation-name: loader-animation;
     animation-duration: 3s;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 }
```

And my html

```
<div class="loader">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

And a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devconcept/wbyzy9jL/3/) with the code

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is because you have a heavy break between `49%` and `50%`.

```
 49% {
     width: 100%;
 }

 50% {
     left: 100%;
 }
```

Adding the `left` to the `49%`, and adjusting a few properties of `width`, `left`, etc. gives you an awesome pulsating effect:

```
@keyframes loader-animation {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }
    49% {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0%
    }
    50% {
        left: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
@keyframes loader-animation {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  49% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%
  }
}
.loader {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
.loader .bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  animation-name: loader-animation;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/06w7zwwm/**

If you need a pulsating effect, you need to use two extremes:

```
@keyframes loader-animation {
    0% {
        left: -100%;
    }
    49% {
        left: 100%;
    }
    50% {
        left: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        left: -100%;
    }
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;}
@keyframes loader-animation {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  49% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
.loader {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
.loader .bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  animation-name: loader-animation;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Day 30. Still waiting for the snipped to finish loading

Comment: @NicoO I don't understand. If you are sarcastic, then ha ha! `:D`

Comment: Sorry, this was ment to be a joke ;)

Comment: Your solution is not working. The line is still moving in only one direction and the left margin is still at 0% when it should animate from right to left

Comment: @devconcept Do you want a pulsating effect?

Comment: No. i'ts supposed to go from left to right and then from right to left. A pulsating effect can be easily created changing the animation-timing-function property

Comment: @devconcept Check mine now?

Comment: It will work when you add 

```
animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
```

Meaning the .bar will be updated to below:

```
.loader .bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  animation-name: loader-animation;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}
```

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, you are welcome.
Here is a codepen link:

https://codepen.io/agoiabel/pen/zYGjGOK

to it.

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot @AbelAgoi.

Answer (score 5):

I have slightly changed your code, managed to make it work. Here's what I've changed:

```
 @keyframes loader-animation {
     0% {
         left: -100%;
     }
     49% {
         left: 100%;
     }
     50% {
         left: 100%;
     }
     100% {
         left: -100%;
     }
 }
```

Added `overflow: hidden;` to `.loader`

Added `width: 100%;` to `.loader .bar`

http://jsfiddle.net/wbyzy9jL/5/